# Make bottomNavigationBar expand down to use whole screen in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Flutter and went on to do the [codelabs - first flutter app](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter-codelab-first#0)

Since I'm learning Flutter to develop mobile apps, this tutorials use of `NavigationRail` isn't too good looking on a phone. I tried to switch it out for a `BottomNavigationBar`. When changing the background color of the navbar I noticed it doesnt expand to use the full screen. Is it always like this, or is there something making it display it this way in the code?Could'nt find any useful information about this case.

Is it possible to make the green background cover the, here black, area at the bottom of the screen?
[Area under bar, white when debugging on real device, here it is black](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMvmI.png)

The final code from the tutorial is poorly adjusted to:

```
import 'package:english_words/english_words.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyAppState(),
      child: MaterialApp(
        title: 'Namer App',
        theme: ThemeData(
          useMaterial3: true,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.green),
        ),
        home: MyHomePage(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class MyAppState extends ChangeNotifier {
  var current = WordPair.random();

  void getNext() {
    current = WordPair.random();
    notifyListeners();
  }

  var favorites = <WordPair>[];

  void toggleFavorite() {
    if (favorites.contains(current)) {
      favorites.remove(current);
    } else {
      favorites.add(current);
    }
    notifyListeners();
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  var selectedIndex = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    Widget page;
    switch(selectedIndex){
      case 0:
        page = GeneratorPage();
        break;
      case 1:
        page = FavoritesPage();
        break;
      default:
        throw UnimplementedError('no widget for $selectedIndex');
    }


    return LayoutBuilder(
      builder: (context, constraints) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Center(

            child: page,
          ),

          bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar (

            items: const <BottomNavigationBarItem>[
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.home),
                label: 'Home',
              ),
              BottomNavigationBarItem(
                icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
                label: 'Favorites',
              ),
            ],
            currentIndex: selectedIndex,
            onTap: _onItemTapped,
            backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.secondaryContainer,
            elevation: 0.0,


          ),
        );
      }

    );

  }
  void _onItemTapped(int index){
    setState(() {
      selectedIndex = index;
    });
  }
}



class FavoritesPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();

    if (appState.favorites.isEmpty) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('No favorites yet.'),
      );
    }

    return ListView(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
          child: Text('You have '
              '${appState.favorites.length} favorites:'),
        ),
        for (var pair in appState.favorites)
          ListTile(
            leading: Icon(Icons.favorite),
            title: Text(pair.asLowerCase),
          ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

class GeneratorPage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var appState = context.watch<MyAppState>();
    var pair = appState.current;

    IconData icon;
    if (appState.favorites.contains(pair)) {
      icon = Icons.favorite;
    } else {
      icon = Icons.favorite_border;
    }

    return Center(
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          BigCard(pair: pair),
          SizedBox(height: 10),
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
            children: [
              ElevatedButton.icon(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.toggleFavorite();
                },
                icon: Icon(icon),
                label: Text('Like'),
              ),
              SizedBox(width: 10),
              ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  appState.getNext();
                },
                child: Text('Next'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

class BigCard extends StatelessWidget {
  const BigCard({
    Key? key,
    required this.pair,
  }) : super(key: key);

  final WordPair pair;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var theme = Theme.of(context);
    var style = theme.textTheme.displayMedium!.copyWith(
      color: theme.colorScheme.onPrimary,
    );
    return Card(
      color: theme.colorScheme.primary,
      elevation: 10,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
        child: Text(pair.asLowerCase, style: style),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Tried changing `elevation` to `0.0`, `expandbody` and what not. Nothing seems to be working here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`SystemUiOverlayStyle`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemUiOverlayStyle-class.html) class

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  void initState() {
    SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle.light
        .copyWith(systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.greenAccent));
    super.initState();
  }
```

[image]